# Audio louder than usual until volume is changed

Tags: windows, audio, drivers, windows-10

tonight I upgraded to Windows 10 and began encountering a very strange problem with my audio. I'm not sure what triggers it, but it has happened in two places: when some Flash sources load and on seemingly random unpauses of music in foobar2000. What happens is the sound is louder than it should be - the actual volume in Windows does not change, the sound is just louder.

I can resolve it by simply moving the volume slider in Windows anywhere, then it will begin abiding by Windows's volume setting again. Even moving the volume up a notch will end up making it quieter from what it was. I've been uninstalling and reinstalling drivers all night, does anyone have any idea what could be causing this?

Comment: I have had similar problems with [secure desktop login of KeePass](http://keepass.info/help/kb/sec_desk.html). Windows 10 apparently ignores sound settings in some situations.

Answer (score 3):

I looked at this link and, it seems to have fixed the problem for me.

Into my Play-device -> Right click -> Properties -> Enhancements -> Disable all sound effects .

https://windowsforum.com/threads/audio-louder-than-usual-until-volume-is-changed.211811/

Hope this will also help you.

Answer (score 0):

I know this is not quite a solution but it works (sort of)...

I think the problem is when audio starts again, so basically I never allow it to stop.

I just open spotify or any other app that lets me play a sound (with the lowest possible volume so I can't hear it) on repeat. This way sound never stops working (although for me it feels like it).

I know this is not ideal, but it's better than the sound starting on max which was driving me crazy. Cheers