# Audio louder than usual until volume is changed - Windows 8.1

Tags: windows-8.1, audio

Same issue as this:
[Audio louder than usual until volume is changed](https://superuser.com/questions/946722/audio-louder-than-usual-until-volume-is-changed)
, but I am on Windows 8.1 and the answer doesn't work for me. I've found forum topics about this with solutions involving uninstalling/reinstalling the sound driver and that doesn't work as well. Unlike everyone else I've read about my laptop uses Conexant instead of Realtek, I don't even have a loudness equalization enhancement, I've disabled all enhancements anyway (Night Mode, 3D Immersion, Phantom Speaker).

Comment: What model of laptop do you have?

Comment: @Steven ASUS X550JK-XO045D

Comment: Try updating to the latest audio drivers. I had a similar problem on Windows 10 and that fixed it.

Comment: @DrMoishePippik I did that already. Initially it said I already had the latest driver from 2015, but then I uninstalled it and it auto-installed a driver from 2016. Problem is still there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As a workaround, consider using the generic "High Definition Audio Device" driver built into Windows.

This worked for some users in Windows 10.  It seems worth trying.

Source: [Sound louder than usual when playing media after pausing - Page 3 - Windows 10 Forums](https://www.tenforums.com/drivers-hardware/8949-sound-louder-than-usual-when-playing-media-after-pausing-3.html#post826964)

1. Open Device Manager
2. Expand "Sound, video and game controllers"
3. Update generic device

   1. Right click on "High Definition Audio Device"
   2. Select "Update driver software..."
   3. Click "Browse my computer for driver software"
   4. Select "High Definition Audio Device" and click Next
   5. Click "Yes" on the "Update Driver Warning" dialog
   6. Click "Close"
4. Update specific device

   1. Right click on "Conexant whatever"
   2. Select "Update driver software..."
   3. Click "Browse my computer for driver software"
   4. Select "High Definition Audio Device" and click Next
   5. Click "Yes" on the "Update Driver Warning" dialog
   6. Click "Close"
5. Reboot

Comment: There wasn't a "High Definition Audio Device" in my Device Manager, but it appeared after step 4. It seems to be working now.

Comment: Started using a headset more often recently and with this fix the volume of the headset is really low even at 100. It becomes normal if I install the latest driver again, but then the original problem returns.